# How to compare two excel files and write in third with Python?

Tags: python, excel, compare

I have two Excel files, for example:

**First file:**

```
value1        value2        value3
2342342       jon           marketing
03242347      mike          developer
12523222      linda         designer
```

**Second file:**

```
value1       value2         value3
2342342      jon            23
03242347     karlos         25
```

I want to compare these two files with `value1` and if it finds the same numbers, I want them to write in third excel file, for example:

**Third file:**

```
value1        value2    value3    value4     
2342342       jon       23        marketing
```

I am trying to do this with Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that with **Pandas** package. It can read excel files (*read_csv* or *read_excel* functions, depending on your file extension). After reading, it creates Dataframe which you can join by column of you choice. *Inner join* leaves only the rows with the same values of the chosen column.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv("file1.csv")
df2 = pd.read_csv("file1.csv")

merged = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='inner', on='value1')
merged.to_csv("new_file.csv")
```